# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in a query that runs fine in SQL developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select, jdbc

Below code gives

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

on

```
    private final String DUPLICATE_SQL_1="select abc, count(abc)"
            +"from table_1"
            +"where type= 'NEW'"
            +"and trunc(update_date) = trunc(sysdate)"
            +"group by abc having count(abc)>1";

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(DUPLICATE_SQL_1);
```

Same query worked fine on Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing spaces (you must have a space at the end of each line except the last or at the start of each line except the first):

```
private final String DUPLICATE_SQL_1="select abc, count(abc) "
        +"from table_1 "
        +"where type= 'NEW' "
        +"and trunc(update_date) = trunc(sysdate) "
        +"group by abc having count(abc)>1";
```

Comment: Thanks Eran. That was the only issue it seems :_